# How to merge two Firebird databases

Tags: database, merge, firebird

I need to merge two Firebird databases. The first one contains data from 2014 to 2016 and 2018 to 2019. The second one from 2014 to 2017.

I would like to have all data from 2012 to 2019 in the same database.

Comment: Can I export data from 2nd db 2017 add to first one...?

Comment: Hi, if the first DB is from 2014 to 2016, how can you get the data from 2012 to 2014?

Comment: yes you can try this out http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq86/

Comment: So, what is stopping you from merging the databases? What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

try use on external in the procedure

for example:

```
create or alter procedure GET_ALL_DATA
 returns (
   BASE integer,
   ID integer,
   NAME varchar(250))
 as
 begin
   for execute statement 'select 1, id, name from dict_assortment'
    into base, id, name do
    suspend;
   for execute statement 'select 2, id, name from dict_assortment'
    on external 'C:\base2000\Db\db.fdb'
    into base, id, name do
    suspend;
 end
```